# Managing State for Overlay Dismissed Components in Vuetify

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm building out a `vuetify/nuxt` frontend for the first time, and I've moved my `v-navigation-drawer` component out of the `default.vue` layout, and into it's own component, so that it can be reused in multiple layouts.

The activator for this drawer still remains in the `default.vue` component, so I added a `sidebar` state to vuex:

```
export const state = () => ({
    baseurl: 'http://example.com/api/',
    sidebar: false,
    authenticated: false,
    token: null,
    user: null,
})
```

The mutator for the sidebar looks like so:

```
export const mutations = {
    toggleSidebar(state) {
        state.sidebar = !state.sidebar;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when opening the drawer, but because the drawer is dismissed via clicking the overlay, or clicking off of sidebar (if you've turned the overlay off) vuex throws a huge error:

[image]

How can I make this work correctly through vuex?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of binding the drawer's model directly to `$store.state.sidebar`, use a computed setter in the drawer component. Note that you *must* pass in the new value from the drawer itself, don't just toggle whatever's already in the store.

```html
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" ...>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      drawer: {
        get () {
          return this.$store.state.sidebar
        },
        set (val) {
          this.$store.commit('sidebar', val)
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```js
// vuex mutation
sidebar (state, val) {
  state.sidebar = val
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter
https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html

Another option is to bind the prop and event separately

```html
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer :value="$store.state.sidebar" @input="$store.commit('sidebar', $event)" ...>
</template>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: You are a flippin genius my friend! To my credit I was VERY close to this ... I just wasn't passing the value into the mutation. But finally after trying everything under the sun .... bingo!  Thanks a ton.

Comment: You are genius. This is what i have looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! The missing guide to Vuetify v-navigation-drawer ! There are open issues on Vuetify about this.... And the answer - for most cases - is yours!

Comment: This is the answer to so many unanswered posts. Can anyone explain where `val` comes from and how it is set? Is it just a default that is generated with v-model?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields) package which enables two-way data binding for states saved in a Vuex store.

It makes the code clear, readable more than the normal way (as in the accepted answer).

#### Basic example:

**in your store file**

```js
// Import the `getField` getter and the `updateField`
// mutation function from the `vuex-map-fields` module.
import { getField, updateField } from 'vuex-map-fields';

export const state = () => ({
    baseurl: 'http://example.com/api/',
    sidebar: false,
    authenticated: false,
    token: null,
    user: null,
})

export const getters = {
   // Add the `getField` getter to the
   // `getters` of your Vuex store instance.
   getField,
}

export const mutations = {
   // Add the `updateField` mutation to the
   // `mutations` of your Vuex store instance.
   updateField,
}
```

**in your component**

```js
template>
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="sidebar" ...>
</template>

<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields';

export default {
  computed: {
    // The `mapFields` function takes an array of
    // field names and generates corresponding
    // computed properties with getter and setter
    // functions for accessing the Vuex store.
    ...mapFields([
      'baseurl',
      'sidebar',
      // etc...
    ]),
    }
  }
</script>
```

for more details, you can check its [githab page](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields)