# Better way to handle Vuetify Navigatin Drawer with Vuex

Tags: vuex, vuetify.js

I have a `Header` component with the button that toggles the navigation drawer state.

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar app dark>
    <v-btn @click="$store.commit('toggleCart')" icon>
      <v-icon>mdi-cart</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Header",
  methods: {
    ...mapState(["cartOpen"])
  }
};
</script>
```

The `Cart` component has the vuetify navigation drawer.

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer :value="cartOpen" absolute temporary right>Products in Cart</v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Cart",

  methods: {
    ...mapState(["cartOpen"])
  },
  computed: {
    cartOpen: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.cartOpen;
      },
      set(state) {
        this.$store.cartOpen = state;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And my store file looks like this

```
export const state = () => ({
  cartOpen: false
})

export const mutations = {
  toggleCart(state) {
    state.cartOpen = !state.cartOpen;
  }
}

export const getters = {
  cartOpen(state) {
    return state.cartOpen;
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected the first time I click the toggle button, then I click outside of the drawer. It closes but the state `cartOpen` is still `true` and therefore the drawer value is `true`.
So, the next time, I have to click twice on the button to open the drawer again. one click to set the value to false and once again to set it to true. 
[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFRTY.gif)

How do I update the state when the drawer is closed by clicking outside?
Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing State for Overlay Dismissed Components in Vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442621/managing-state-for-overlay-dismissed-components-in-vuetify)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are already on the right path, Our both ways are almost the same, we just have little differences. Here's how I did it.

**My navigation bar**. I used v-model not value

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="left_sidebar_status" app pb-0>
```

now left_sidebar_status is a computed property. Here it is

```
computed: {
    left_sidebar_status:{
        get: function () {
                return this.$store.getters.left_sidebar_status
        },
        set: function (newValue) {

        }
    }
}
```

then in my header, We just did the same.

```
methods : {
    leftSlide: function() {
        this.$store.commit('CHANGE_LEFT_SIDEBAR')
    },
}
```

and trigger the sidebar like this

```
<v-btn icon class="hidden-xs-only" @click="leftSlide">
     <v-icon>{{!$store.getters.left_sidebar_status ? 'mdi-arrow-right' : 'mdi-arrow-left'}}</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

last is in my vuex.We also did the same

```
CHANGE_LEFT_SIDEBAR(state) {
     state.left_sidebar = !state.left_sidebar
},
```

**Hopefully you could get an idea on that, mine is working well**

Answer (score -1):

Please check this discussion https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1263 I see someone uses custom directive for that, check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-click-outside .

But generally I'm surprised that those events are not exist on the core of Vuetify. I hope they will add it in the future.